# Squid access log not logging CONNECT full urls

Tags: squid

I need to log all HTTPS connects to test my clients app. How can I configure SQUID to log all the HTTPS traffic urls?

Only "CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1" is there in the access logs but I get full URLs for GET POST Requests.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me out with logging full request headers in SQUID3 or in ZED ATTACK PROXY ?

ZAPROXY doesn't even let the HTTPS urls through.

Comment: I recommend read the book: *Squid Proxy Server 3.1 Beginners Guide*.

Answer (score 5):

Squid doesn't log the full URL because squid has no way of knowing the full URL.

HTTP and HTTPS requests are handled completely differently by squid. For HTTP requests squid acts mostly like an HTTP server, but for HTTPS requests squid just sets up a socket with the remote server, patches in the client and steps out of the way.

If squid tried to talk directly to the remote server itself and pass the connection on to the client it would essentially be attempting to perform a man-in-the-middle attack.

Let's look at a few sample requests to http://example.com/foo/bar/baz to see exactly what requests look like.

#### Direct http request

```
GET /foo/bar/baz HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.15.5
Host: example.com
Accept: */*
```

#### Http request as seen from squid

```
GET example.com/foo/bar/baz HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.15.5
Host: example.com
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

As you can see, HTTP requests are almost identical, just a few extra headers, and most notably, the `GET` line requests the full URI.

#### Direct https request

Not much to see here, everything is encrypted, `tcpdump` shows a socket is opened to `example.com` but every bit of that interaction is encrypted (hooray for privacy!).

#### Https request as seen from squid

```
CONNECT example.com:443 HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com:443
User-Agent: curl/7.15.5
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

When squid receives that request it has everything it needs to know, it can then open a socket to the requested server, at which point the client and server perform an TLS handshake and finally begin talking normal HTTP (just like the first example), with squid just passing the encrypted traffic having no ability to see any deeper.

So when squid logs these requests it gives you everything it has, with HTTP it was able to see the full path so it logs the full path, with HTTPS it only has the host and port, so that's what it logs.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to run Squid as an SSL Gateway in order for the passed traffic to be fully logged. If you were to capture the traffic on the wire, you would understand why you only get the limited information in your logs.

Comment: great! But could you be more specific on how to get it right?